# Moving a DOM element with append()?

Tags: jquery, appendto

I have a `div` element like

```
<div id="move">Something</div>
```

...that I'd like to **move** from one position to another in the DOM. Can I do this with `appendTo()`, like so:

```
$('#move').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).appendTo('#another-container').fadeIn(500);
});
```

...or will this duplicate it?

If it's being duplicated, there would be two elements with the same `id` in the DOM. How could I avoid this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the `appendTo` method moves elements from the DOM tree. If you want to copy an element, `.clone()` is used.

Example:

```
Body:   <div>
           <a>Test</a>
        </div>
        <span></span>
jQuery code:
   $("a").appendTo("span");

After:  <div></div>
        <span>
           <a>Test</a>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 6):

I took it directly from jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );
```

"If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.append` or `.after` or similar methods.

```
<ul class="list1">
  <li>You wanted to move this element!</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
  <li></li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="moveIt()">Move element</button>
```

So the code to move the first `.li` from `.list1` to `.list2` will be:

```
function moveIt() {
  var elementToBeMoved = $(".list1 li:first");
  $(".list2 li:first").append(elementToBeMoved);
}
```

[Working pen](https://codepen.io/ilyanice/pen/dRpmLL)